# How to refresh BottomSheet display with updated state in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I  have a statefull widget in which I have a List field  called filters:
I allow the user to click a button to show the BottomSheet where I use a "Filters" widget and pass in the filters array as a parameter.

What I want now is to be able to change the filter List, for example calling removeFilter method  and have that updated in the BottomSheet?

In the code below, when I call removeFilter, it correctly updates the filters state with the new filter array, but the bottom modal sheet is not updated.

How do I get the state to be reflected in the BottomSheet (without needing to rebuild the bottom sheet with every change)?

```
  List<dynamic> filters = [];


  void removeFilter(String field) {
    List<dynamic> updatedFilters =
        filters.where((element) => element['field'] != field).toList();

    this.setState(() {
      filters = updatedFilters;
    });
  }

  void showFiltersScreen(BuildContext context, String field) {

    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (context) {
        return  Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: Filters(
            blockColor: widget.blockData.color,
            tableinfo: _tableinfo,
            filters: filters,
            removeFilter: this.removeFilter,
            setState: setState,
          ),
        );
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the showBottomSheet from the ScaffoldState.

This will show the bottomSheet and return a controller PersistentBottomSheetController. with this controller you can call `controller.SetState((){})` which will re-render the bottomSheet

for example

```
List<dynamic> filters = [];
PersistentBottomSheetController _controller; // <------ Instance variable
final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>(); // <---- Another instance variable


void removeFilter(String field) {
  List<dynamic> updatedFilters =
      filters.where((element) => element['field'] != field).toList();

  this.setState(() {
    filters = updatedFilters;
  });
 }

void showFiltersScreen(BuildContext context, String field) {

_controller = await _scaffoldKey.currentState.showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (context) {
    return  Padding(
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
      child: Filters(
        blockColor: widget.blockData.color,
        tableinfo: _tableinfo,
        filters: filters,
        removeFilter: this.removeFilter,
        setState: setState,
      ),
    );
 });
}
```

Comment: Tried adding that, but the showModalBottomSheet line gives the error: The method 'showModalBottomSheet' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

Comment: I was missing assigning key to Scaffold, so it's working from that perspective. However, the ShowBottomSheet is different than ShowBottomModalSheet, as ShowBottomModalSheet allows the parameter isScrollControlled, which I need to get the correct behavior when a user clicks into the textformfield. With ShowBottomSheet, there is no such parameter, and when clicking into a field, it takes up the whole screen. Any solution?

Comment: you can call controller.SetState((){}) which will update the bottomSheet